# Launch Chrome Extension from Mac Dock

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shortcut

Is it possible to put an icon in the Mac dock for a chrome extension I'm working on.

Here's the extension code just for reference. manifest.json:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "Habitica",
   "author": "Sam Dale",
   "description": "A launcher to quickly get to Habitica. Especially great for Mac users.",
   "version": "1.0",
   "icons": {"16": "habitica-logo-16.png", "128": "habitica-logo-128.png", "300": "habitica-logo-300.png"},

   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "habitica-logo-128.png",
      "default_title": "Habitica"
   },
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
   }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://habitica.com/#/tasks" });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to interact with the dock. So, no easy way.

I can think of several *complicated* ways to do it, but in general I would recommend avoiding that idea.

1. One can add a shortcut to a non-existing webpage, say, `https://launch-my-awesome-extension.horse/`, and intercept it with [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

   Note that one can't use a link to a Chrome extension page to sidestep `webRequest` requirements: such links are likely to be ignored if you try to open them via a shortcut due to elevated privilege of `chrome-extension://` pages.
2. Write a companion native app and use [Native Messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) with all the usual consequences.

   Complication: Chrome can only initiate Native Messaging, you cannot launch an app to tell Chrome something; so there must be some resident component already launched when you click the dock icon.

Both are cumbersome and not really a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.